# How do I create a hidden list instance, such as the transform in Unity3D

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, instance-variables

Unity has the [Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) for every GameObject.

Unity lets you do this:

```
foreach(Transform t in transform)
   t.name;
```

That piece of code lets you traverse a list of child Transforms found nested under your object's `transform`. So in this case `transform` behaves like a list.

At the same time this `transform` variable, that all GameObjects have, lets you do things like any normal instance variable does:

```
Vector3 pos = transform.position;
Quaternion rot = transform.rotation;
```

---

How can I create something like that for my own classes? That is, something that has the power to behave as a list as well as a normal instance variable?

---

To me this is some wizardry. If I wanted the same functionality I would need to do it like this:

```
public class MyTransform
{
   private MyTransform [] list;
   private Vector3 position;
} 

public class MyGameObject 
{
    protected MyTransform transform = new MyTransform();

    void Start()
    {
       transform.list[i] = obj;
       transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: They're public/protected fields on the the base class, `MonoBehavior`.

Comment: @Mephy okay, but how do they look like behind the scenes?

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [implement `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#exampleToggle) such that it traverses the child tree...

```
class Transform : IEnumerable<Transform>
{
    private IList<Transform> childTransforms;
    public IEnumerator<Transform> GetEnumerator()
    {
        //change to Queue<T> and use Enqueue/Dequeue instead of
        //Push/Pop for breadth-first traversal
        Stack<Transform> stk=new Stack<Transform>();
        stk.Push(this); //or items in childTransforms if 'this' isn't needed
        while(stk.Any())
        {
            var v = stk.Pop();
            yield v;
            if(v.childTransforms == null) continue;
            foreach(var child in v.childTransforms)
            {
                stk.Push(child);
            }
        }
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement IEnumerator/IEnumerable in your class.

Actually, you can create a private list and expose it with IEnumerator

```
public class SomeObject : IEnumerable<SomeObject>
{  
    private List<SomeObject> myList = new List<SomeObject>();

    public IEnumerable<SomeObject>(){
        return myList.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```